# How should I clean up memory using SharedMemory in python 3.8? Close() and unlink() methods do not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have the following code where I have a consumer and a producer. The producer sends a batch of 4k images to the consumer. In practice a have multiple consumers and my intuition says that using shared memory must be the most efficient way to transfer these images. The problem is that the following code seems to allocate memory without cleaning it up.

I warn you to run this code with caution if you have a small RAM memory.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

from multiprocessing.context import Process
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
from multiprocessing.dummy import freeze_support

batch_size = 10


def create_shared_memory(images, sm_name):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=sm_name, create=True, size=images.nbytes)
    np_array = np.ndarray(images.shape, dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shm.buf)
    np_array[:] = images[:]

    return shm


def consume_images(batch_names_queue):
    while True:
        batch_name = batch_names_queue.get()
        start = time.time()

        existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=batch_name)
        _ = np.ndarray((batch_size, 2160, 3840, 3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
        existing_shm.close()
        existing_shm.unlink()
        end = time.time()

        print("reading shared memory time " + str(end - start))


def put_images(batch_names_queue, batch_images):
    index = 0
    while True:
        index += 1
        name = str(index)

        start = time.time()
        existing_shm = create_shared_memory(batch_images, name)
        batch_names_queue.put(name)
        end = time.time()

        print("creating shared memory time " + str(end - start))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    image = cv.imread("./4k.jpg")

    batch_images = np.stack([image] * batch_size, axis=0)
    batch_names_queue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)

    produce = Process(target=put_images, args=(batch_names_queue, batch_images,))
    produce.start()

    consume = Process(target=consume_images, args=(batch_names_queue,))
    consume.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but the shared-memory is created inside a loop. No wonder it increases in size. Create it in the main-function and and provide the share-memory object as argument to your producer/consumer.

Comment: I think you are right, you helped me on finding a better solution.